# Raspberry Pi web server remove .html/.php from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, raspberry-pi, webserver

I'm using my Raspberry Pi as an webserver with a domain that i bought on strato.de with a dyndns. I attached a file named `.htacces` to my project with following code.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I also tried this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.htm [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Before hosting my website on the webspace from STRATO.de everything worked with the first version, which you can see above. But not its only giving me an 404.

[image: Not found Raspbian Server]

I just want to remove the ending `.html`/`.php` and other from my URL.

Comment: `.htacces` is the name of the file? If so that is a typo. Is `.htaccess` enabled for usage as well?

Comment: oh, thanks i didnt knew that i have to activatre the usage.
THANKS ALOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in into pi
2. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`
3. Add:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       # AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
4. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart oder service apache2 restart`